# Find solutions of $\alpha x^n = \ln x$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

How can I find the solutions of $$\alpha x^n = \ln x$$ when $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n\in \mathbb{Q}$? Or, if it is not possible to have closed form solutions, how can I prove that there exist one (or there is no solution) and that it is unique? (I'm particularly interested in the cases $n=2$, $n=1$, and $n=1/2$).

Comment: $n=1/2$ is not a natural number. :)

Comment: @MarkFantini You're right!

Comment: Why not $n \in \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: I feel that restriction to natural numbers in this case is not going to make things much easier. But I don't know a solution, who knows? :)

Comment: @MarkFantini And for those special cases?

Comment: Seems unlikely. Plotting $x,x^2,x^3, x^4, x^{1/2}$ and $\ln(x)$ gives no solutions. I'll try with small values of $\alpha$. Starting close to $\alpha = 1/3$ you have an intersection of $\alpha x$ with $\ln(x)$. Doesn't look good for finding a closed form solution, though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no point in restricting $n$ to be rational.

Set $x^n=t$, so $x=t^{1/n}$ and the equation becomes
$$
\alpha t=\frac{1}{n}\log t
$$
or $n\alpha t=\log t$ and we can so study the problem
$$
kt=\log t
$$
Consider the function
$$
f(t)=kt-\log t
$$
defined for $t>0$. We have
$$
\lim_{t\to0}f(t)=\infty
$$
and
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}f(t)=
\begin{cases}
\infty & \text{if $k>0$}\\
-\infty & \text{if $k\le 0$}
\end{cases}
$$
(check it).

The derivative is
$$
f'(t)=k-\frac{1}{t}=\frac{kt-1}{t}
$$
which is everywhere negative if $k\le0$, so in this case the equation has one solution.

For $k>0$, the minimum is attained at $1/k$ and $f(1/k)=1+\log k$. So we have

- no solution if $k>e^{-1}$,
- one solution if $k=e^{-1}$,
- two solutions if $0<k<e^{-1}$.

Since $k=n\alpha$, it's easy to translate the result in terms of $\alpha$ in the cases $n=2$, $n=1$ and $n=1/2$.

Comment: Really impressive. Thank you very much, professor.

Comment: This is how pros do it. Amazing!

Answer (score 0):

In the case that $\alpha n\not =0$, we have
$$\alpha x^n = \ln x$$
$$ \alpha nx^{n}= n\ln x$$
$$ \alpha nx^{n}= \ln x^{n}$$
$$ e^{\alpha nx^{n}} = x^{n}$$
$$ 1= \frac{x^{n}}{e^{\alpha nx^{n}}}$$
$$ 1= x^{n}e^{-\alpha nx^{n}} $$
$$ -\alpha n= -\alpha nx^{n}e^{-\alpha nx^{n}} $$
$$ W(-\alpha n)= -\alpha nx^{n} $$
$$ -\frac{W(-\alpha n)}{\alpha n}= x^{n} $$
$$ x=\left(-\frac{W(-\alpha n)}{\alpha n}\right)^{\frac1n}$$
Where $W$ is the [Lambert W function](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).